# qt Add qGraphicsitem which has new qGraphicsItem in constructor to qGrahicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I Add custom QGraphicsitem(CoauthorGraphItem) in qGraphicsView's scene.
And in QGraphicsItem's constructor create new qGraphicsItem(NodeItem, EdgeItem).
And then in scene, view qGraphicsItem(CoauthorGraphItem) also qGraphicsItem produced by constructor(NodeItem, EdgeItem).
I want to know why this happened. I can't find this document. help me.

here's my code

```
 // CoauthorGraphItem is inherit QGraphicsItem
    CoauthorGraphItem::CoauthorGraphItem(ifstream& fin)
    {
        ... // read file and create graph data

        for (boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = boost::edges(*graph); ei != ei_end; ++ei) {     
            u = source(*ei, *graph);
            v = target(*ei, *graph);
            Point p1 = position[u];
            Point p2 = position[v];

            //make edge item and it's also inherit QGraphicsItem
            EdgeItem *edge;
            edge = new EdgeItem(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1], QColor(Qt::black), 0, index[ei->m_source], index[ei->m_target]);

            edge->setPos(p1[0], p1[1]);
            edgeList << edge;
        }
        //add nodes that's graph nodes
        for (boost::tie(vi, vi_end) = vertices(*graph); vi != vi_end; ++vi) {
            Point p = position[*vi];
            std::string name = label[*vi];

            //make nodeItem and it's also inherit QGraphicsItem
            NodeItem *node;
            node = new NodeItem(p[0], p[1], QColor(Qt::green), QString(name.c_str()), vInfo[i], vcoauthor[i]);
            node->setPos(QPointF(p[0], p[1]));
            nodeList << node;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify this a little bit?
You have a custom QGraphicsitem (The one called NodeItem?) which you add to a scene. In the constructor of this custom QGraphicsitem you create another QGraphicsItem. Now you see both items in your scene? Or you're seeing only the first item but want to see both? Not sure if I get what your actual problem is. Can you add the code of your constructor?

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the codes. I add to a scene CoauthorGraphItem which is graph data and then I saw CoauthorGraphItem, NodeItem and EdgeItem.
I use boost graph.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies it a bit but one think I still don't get, you say: " And then in scene, view qGraphicsItem(CoauthorGraphItem) also qGraphicsItem produced by constructor(NodeItem, EdgeItem). I want to know why this happened.". Is the issue that you can not see NodeItem and EdgeItem in the Scene/View or you can see them but you don't want them to be seen? If you need a way to add it, you could use `QGraphicsScene *QGraphicsItem::scene() const` to get a pointer to the scene where the CoauthorGraphItem was added, then, call `void QGraphicsScene::addItem(QGraphicsItem *item)` and add it to scene

Comment: I can see them but I don't want them to be seen. What should I do??

Comment: Now I get what your problem is. Interesting question, I'm not sure if it's somewhere covered why it's happening as it's kind of unusual to create QGraphicsItems in another QGraphicsItem, I've never seen it. 
If you don't want them to be part of the scene, why are they inheriting QGraphicsItem? Could you make just a struct that represents NodeItem and EdgeItem?

Comment: Or you could just simple hide them by calling `setVisible(false)`, but this is just a workaround. I personally wouldn't make them inherit QGraphicsItem if I don't want them to be shown on the scene.